# the place where lots of roads meet

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

what to call the point at which all paths meet?

they often become major trade hubs, or busy bustling cities, because it's a huge intersection, a crossroads but on a greater scale.

> If you control the _______ you control the world.

I realise I was most likely searching for an idiom, a historical town or so that has come into common usage and now means what I describe above.

Comment: I’m tempted to suggest *Rome*, tongue firmly in cheek.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think there is a word as you describe it that would fit in your example sentence other than _hub_. None of _intersection_, _crossroad_, or _junction_ (given in an answer) really work. I think you more likely want the destination (or origin) of many different roads, as @Lawrence suggested. E.g. "If you control _Rome_, you control the world".

Comment: I would say "crossroads".  It has a metaphorical meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Looking to your example, I'll suggest two words.

**Hub** check the ***entry 2*** in [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hub)

> The effective center of an activity, region, or ***network***.
>
> > "Today, the area around the vast pond is the hub of commercial activity in the city."

And, the second word is **Junction.**

> A place where **two or more roads** or railway lines meet.
>
> > (*used in the sentence figuratively*) “Zone III is considered a very attractive project to invest in, given its prime location in the international ***business junction*** that saw land prices growing continuously,” the company says.

Answer (score 1):

On reading the title, I was immediately going to answer *intersection*—until I saw that it was already in the question.

I can't think of a different word (other than *intersection* or *crossroads*) that is literally about roads, and you've already used *hub* in your question.

I can, however, provide two related words—as defined at Merriam-Webster:

[**Nexus**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nexus)

> 1 : CONNECTION, LINK
>   // the *nexus* between teachers and students
>   *also* : a causal link
>   // the *nexus* between poverty and crime
>   2 : a connected group or series
>   // a *nexus* of theories
>   // a *nexus* of relationships
>   3 : CENTER, FOCUS 
>   // The bookstore has become something of a *nexus* for the downtown neighborhood.
>   —Jane Smiley

[**Core**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/core)

> **1** : a central and often foundational part usually distinct from the enveloping part by a difference in nature
>   // the *core* of the city

Comment: Another popular term in the US is "corner".  There are many places called "Four Corners" or "Five Corners".

Answer (score 0):

Potentially [confluence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confluence), Merriam Webster:

> a coming or flowing together, meeting, or gathering at one point